# Transfer row to column Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Is below example good solution to get in one row all employee where job = 'MANAGER'

```
with cte as (
Select
      job,
      case when SAL = 2850 then ename end as SAL_1,
      case when SAL = 2450 then ename end as SAL_2,
      case when SAL = 2975 then ename end as SAL_3
from
     (Select * from emp where job = 'MANAGER') 
)
Select job,MIN(SAL_1) as SAL_1,MIN(SAL_2) as SAL_2,MIN(SAL_3) as SAL_3 from  cte
group by job
```

Comment: Please add sample data to your question, to better explain what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen  get in one row all employee where job = 'MANAGER' in above example is 3 employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't a good way to show one row with all managers. Your query can only show up to three managers, and it doesn't even guarantee to show any manager at all. This depends on whether they happen to have one of the three salaries or not.

When writing a query you don't know how many managers there will be (and how much they earn) at the time someone runs the query. But in SQL queries you must state which (this includes "how many") columns to select.

Three options:

1. Just select rows (`select * from emp where job = 'MANAGER'`) and let your app care about the display (i.e. loop through the rows and fill a grid with columns accordingly). This is the typical solution.
2. Count managers (`select count(*) from emp where job = 'MANAGER'`). Then build a separate query with as many columns as there are managers found and run this query. This technique is called "dynamic SQL". You can do this from your app or use Oracle's built-in programming language PL/SQL.
3. Put all the names into one column, i.e. have a string column that contains all names separated by comma, semicolon or whatever. Use `LISTAGG` for this.